# valid GitHub api v4 query keeps returning error "Problems parsing JSON"

Tags: curl, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Here is an example of a cURL query to the GitHub api v4 that keeps returning an error:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -X POST -d " \
 { \
   \"query\": \"query { repositoryOwner(login: \"brianzelip\") { id } }\" \
 } \
" https:\/\/api.github.com\/graphql
```

The error that is returned:

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

**Why do I keep getting this error?**

---

According to the [GH api v4 docs about forming query calls](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#communicating-with-graphql), the above cURL command is valid. Here's what the docs say that backs up my claim that the above cURL command is valid:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -X POST -d " \
 { \
   \"query\": \"query { viewer { login }}\" \
 } \
" https://api.github.com/graphql
```

> Note: The string value of "query" must escape newline characters or
>   the schema will not parse it correctly. For the POST body, use outer
>   double quotes and escaped inner double quotes.

When I enter the above query into the [GitHub GraphQL API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/), I get the expected result. The format of the above cURL command looks like this for the GH GraphQL Explorer:

```
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "brianzelip") {
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it awesome how GraphQL Explore parses the JSON correctly, but when using the API using the exact same query it's problematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape nested double quotes in `query` JSON field, your actual body would be :

```
{
 "query": "query { repositoryOwner(login: \"brianzelip\") { id } }"
}
```

So replace `\"brianzelip\"` with `\\\"brianzelip\\\"` :

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -d " \
 { \
   \"query\": \"query { repositoryOwner(login: \\\"brianzelip\\\") { id } }\" \
 } \
" https://api.github.com/graphql
```

You can also use single quotes instead of double quotes to wrap the body :

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -d '
 {
   "query": "query { repositoryOwner(login: \"brianzelip\") { id } }"
 }
' https://api.github.com/graphql
```

You could also use [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) :

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -d @- https://api.github.com/graphql <<EOF
{
    "query": "query { repositoryOwner(login: \"brianzelip\") { id } }"
}
EOF
```

Comment: How to support multiple Query schema  ?. My query schema as
{
  viewer {
    login
  }
  codesOfConduct {
    body
    id
    key
    name
    resourcePath
    url
  }